# how to stop ajax request after type:Post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I am sending post request via ajax to controller/function and getting back result in success: and it loads result on same page as it does always, but I want to quit ajax when I reach at controller/function, because I want to load different view there $this->load->view('htmlfile').

```
function test() {

    var wingId = $('#wing_id').val();
    var classId = $('#class_id').val();
    var sectionId = $('#section_id').val();
    var gender = $('#gender').val();        

    $('#error').hide();

    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url()?>admin/library/totalStudentsReportPrint/",

        data: {

            wingId: wingId,
            classId: classId,
            sectionId: sectionId,
            gender: gender

        },
        type: "post",

        success: function (result) {
            $('#data_result').html(result);

        }
    });

}
```

Php Controller function

```
function totalStudentsReportPrint(){

    $student_data['wingId'] = $_POST['wingId'];
    $student_data['classId'] = $_POST['classId'];
    $student_data['sectionId'] = $_POST['sectionId'];
    $student_data['gender'] = $_POST['gender'];          


 $this->load->view('institute/admin/library/total_students_btm_tbl_print',$student_data);
}
```

Comment: i dont understand your problem? You want to load other template? Why you dont send template path via ajax and check the $_POST value inside the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you want is to abort the $.ajax call, right? take a look to [Abort Ajax requests using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery) for the answer.

However, you cannot abort it from PHP. The $.ajax is running in your client browser, not in your PHP server. And the $.ajax call runs PHP in a separate thread, vs the PHP which loads your view.
All you can eventually do is when you want to load a new view, you certainly have an action on the browser made by the client. Before sending the request to your PHP server, you may want to abort the $.ajax call first.
Another way is to have a PHP shared memory variable, that you set when loading the view, and implement your $.ajax PHP call handler suck a way that you stop processing if that variable is set for that session. A bit complicated vs  simply let it go.